# long running py.test stop at first failure

Tags: python, pytest

I am using [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/), and the test execution is supposed to run until it encounters an exception. If the test never encounters an exception it should continue running for the rest of time or until I send it a SIGINT/SIGTERM.

Is there a programmatic way to tell `pytest` to stop running on the first failure as opposed to having to do this at the command line?

Comment: Can you show your code for how you're invoking pytest programatically?

Answer (score 172):

```
pytest -x           # stop after first failure
pytest --maxfail=2  # stop after two failures
```

See the [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/usage.html#stopping-after-the-first-or-n-failures).

Answer (score 47):

**pytest** has the option `-x` or `--exitfirst` which stops the execution of the tests instanly on first error or failed test.

**pytest** also has the option `--maxfail=num` in which `num` indicates the number of errors or failures required to stop the execution of the tests.

```
pytest -x            # if 1 error or a test fails, test execution stops 
pytest --exitfirst   # equivalent to previous command
pytest --maxfail=2   # if 2 errors or failing tests, test execution stops
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use [addopts](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#confval-addopts)  in `pytest.ini` file. It does not require invoking any command line switch.

```
# content of pytest.ini
[pytest]
addopts = --maxfail=2  # exit after 2 failures
```

You can also set env variable `PYTEST_ADDOPTS` before test is run.

If you want to use python code to exit after first failure, you can use this code:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def exit_pytest_first_failure():
    if pytest.TestReport.outcome == 'failed':
        pytest.exit('Exiting pytest')
```

This code applies `exit_pytest_first_failure` fixture to all test and exits pytest in case of first failure.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'TestReport'